# Using sftp << INPUT via golang os/exec

Tags: go

What I want to do is exporting a file from my server via SFTP, in golang.

Here is the troubling code

```
cmd = exec.Command("sftp", "login@sftp.com", `INPUT
    cd /some/path
    put file.gz
    quit
    INPUT`)
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(stderr.String())
    os.Exit(1)
}
fmt.Println("done")
```

It gets to `done` but doesn't import `file.gz`.

Comment: You import with a `get` and upload with a `put`. If it is import, you need to change the `put` to `get`.

Comment: consider as an alternative this [sftp package](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/sftp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

```
cmd = exec.Command("sftp", "login@sftp.com")
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(`cd some/path
put file.gz
quit`)
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(stderr.String())
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
err = cmd.Wait()
```

I set the commands I need to do once I'm in the STFP by setting `cmd.Stdin`

`cmd.Start()` and `cmd.Wait()` starts the command and stops when the whole command is done.